# Python - Replace a very long string into integer

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a HUGE dataset and I'm looking to improve ways to work more efficient with it. One alternative is replacing strings (ids) by integers. However, I need to do this transformation in the most efficient (less RAM used) way. Currently I would do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Customer_ID': ['AWE','GRA', 'GRA', 'FAOOS', '1293912ASJDAS', '1293912ASJDAS', '1293912ASJDAS'],
             'X2': [76,858,68,678,8678,78,6788],
             'X3': [312,3123,123,54,3523,56,2346]})

unique_ids = df['Customer_ID'].drop_duplicates().tolist()

df_ = pd.DataFrame({'unique_ids': unique_ids,
              'int_ids': list(range(0,len(unique_ids)))
    
})

df.merge(df_, how='left', left_on='Customer_ID', right_on='unique_ids').drop(['Customer_ID', 'unique_ids'], axis=1)
```

[image]

But it takes too long (the real data has 20M rows) and a lot of RAM, it's any way to improve this? (Any efficient package is welcome for this specific task)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
df['id'] = df.Customer_ID.astype('category').cat.codes

df
 
     Customer_ID    X2    X3  id
0            AWE    76   312   1
1            GRA   858  3123   3
2            GRA    68   123   3
3          FAOOS   678    54   2
4  1293912ASJDAS  8678  3523   0
5  1293912ASJDAS    78    56   0
6  1293912ASJDAS  6788  2346   0
```

Comment: Nice solution! But how can you assure that there will be a distinct `id` for every distinct `Customer_ID`?

Comment: @Chris because it has been factorized. ie it has been put into Categories. That sthe essence/putpose of categories